# error: package com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo.R does not exist

Tags: android-studio, offline, mapbox-android

When I try to run Mapbox offline and use their template from there website :

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/download-a-simple-offline-map/

I keep getting this error, I tried to google a few things but there was no proper answer -  the closest i got was this:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/16102

This is the error :

error: package com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo does not exist
import com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo.R;

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `import com.mapbox.mapboxandroiddemo.R;` line at the top of your file. This should then let your Android Studio suggest a new import of your project's `R` import line, rather than https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo 's